# NodeJS + MongoDB: Getting data from collection with findOne ()

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I have a collection "companies" with several objects. Every object has "_id" parameter. I'm trying to get this parameter from db:

```
app.get('/companies/:id',function(req,res){
db.collection("companies",function(err,collection){
    console.log(req.params.id);
    collection.findOne({_id: req.params.id},function(err, doc) {
        if (doc){
            console.log(doc._id);
        } else {
            console.log('no data for this company');
        }
    });
});
});
```

So, I request companies/4fcfd7f246e1464d05000001 (4fcfd7f246e1464d05000001 is _id-parma of a object I need) and findOne returns nothing, that' why console.log('no data for this company'); executes.

I'm absolutely sure that I have an object with _id="4fcfd7f246e1464d05000001". What I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

**However, I've just noticed that id is not a typical string field. That's what mViewer shows:**

```
"_id": {
        "$oid": "4fcfd7f246e1464d05000001"
    },
```

Seems to be strange a bit...

Comment: That's an ObjectId. In your query you should construct one from the string (I'm surprised that the library doesn't do it for you).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You need to construct the ObjectID and not pass it in as a string.  Something like this should work:

```
var BSON = require('mongodb').BSONPure;
var obj_id = BSON.ObjectID.createFromHexString("4fcfd7f246e1464d05000001");
```

Then, try using that in your find/findOne.

Edit: As pointed out by [Ohad](https://stackoverflow.com/users/455262/ohad-kravchick) in the comments (thanks Ohad!), you can also use:

```
new require('mongodb').ObjectID(req.params.id)
```

Instead of `createFromHexString` as outlined above.

Comment: I tried   var obj_id = BSON.ObjectID.createFromHexString(req.params.id);
  collection.findOne({_id : obj_id},function(err, doc) { And it worked - thank you very much!

Comment: You can use "new require('mongodb').ObjectID(req.params.id)" instead of createFromHexString

Comment: @OhadKravchick works like a charm. I would also up vote if it was an answer

Answer (score 3):

That's because `_id` field in mongo isn't of `string` type (as your `req.params.id`). As suggested in other answers, you should explicitly convert it.

Try [mongoskin](https://github.com/kissjs/node-mongoskin), you could use it like node-mongodb-native driver, but with some sugar. For example:

```js
// connect easier
var db = require('mongoskin').mongo.db('localhost:27017/testdb?auto_reconnect');

// collections
var companies = db.collection('companies');

// create object IDs
var oid = db.companies.id(req.params.id);

// some nice functions…
companies.findById();

//… and bindings
db.bind('companies', {
  top10: function(callback) {
    this.find({}, {limit: 10, sort: [['rating', -1]]).toArray(callback);
  } 
});

db.companies.top10(printTop10);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `findById()` which will take care of the id conversion for you.

```
company = Company.findById(req.params.id, function(err, company) {
    //////////
});
```

Comment: What is Company in this case? What is findById?  Can you link to the documentation?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In case these didn't work for you, this worked for me for accessing a blog post:

```
const getSinglePost = async (req, res) => {

    let id = req.params.id;
    var ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectId;
    const db = await client.db('CMS');

    const data = await db.collection("posts").findOne({ _id: ObjectId(id) })

    if (data) {
        res.status(200).send(data)
    } else res.status(400).send({ message: "no post found" })

}
```