# How to find by object using node and mongo

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am trying to find a specific object in my mongodb, currently I iterate through the entire id and match string by string in jade template engine, but surely there is a more efficient way of doing search object in mongo

```
app.put('/tasks/:id', function(req, res){
  Task.findById(req.params.id, function (err, doc){
    doc.updated_at = new Date();
    doc.task = req.body.task.task;
    doc.save(function(err) {
      if (!err){
        res.redirect('/tasks');
      }
      else {
        // error handling
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Alternatively, I can

```
db.TASK.find(
   { Task: 'blah blah.....' },
)
```

in the command line

but I don't know how to have the server side respond to different task dynamically, that is 'blah blah' should be dynamic and I don't know how to incorporate that into node.js

Any hint would be appreciated

Comment: By the way, you probably shouldn't pull the entire document up just to set/update some fields. See update() and $set.

Comment: Is the { Task: 'blah blah.....' } object the criteria you want to match on?

Comment: {Task:'adding'} would be in the case of what I am tring to do, it will just be some strings that I am searching through the database for

Comment: Possible duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10929443/nodejs-mongodb-getting-data-from-collection-with-findone You may want to use mongoskin or node-mongodb-native packages

Comment: Disregard my comment. I didn't realize you were using mongoose.