# Dot operator not fetching child properties of a Mongoose Document object

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

```
console.log('>>>>>>user = '+ user);
```

outputs

```
>>>>>>user      = { username: 'user1',
  salt: '3303187e50a64889b41a7a1c66d3d3c10b9dec638fdd033bee1221d30d01c5e1',
  hash: 'a174c206d88bee1594bb081dbd32d53420f6ef3d6322104f3d0722d58bc8dd8d',
  _id: 52d3177481daf59c11000001,
  __v: 0 }
```

but

```
console.log('>>>>>>user.hash = '+ user.hash);
```

outputs

```
>>>>>>user.hash = undefined
```

[image]

What could be causing this?

---

Edit: Interestingly, `user._id`, (and *only* it) works. 
[image]

Comment: why not try `user['hash']` ?

Comment: @Mahan Doesn't work either.

Comment: btw, how come is _id: working with you, it does not have quotes and contains letters. As far as I am aware you should get `Unexpected token ILLEGAL ` for this.

Comment: Can you try `console.log('>>>>>>user.hash = ', user.hash);` instead of `console.log('>>>>>>user.hash = '+ user.hash);`?

Comment: @Teemu `user` is an {object}. It's a [model object for mongoDB](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html).

Comment: @dachi Don't know but `_id` is [ObjectID](http://dochub.mongodb.org/core/objectids), set automatically [mongoDB](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html)

Comment: try `console.dir` just to know

Comment: @AlexanderT. [Didn't help either.](http://i.imgur.com/xPXfZhw.png)

Comment: @srvikram13 [doesn't work either.](http://i.imgur.com/SD5f0rD.png)

Comment: @laggingreflex Could you try `for (var key in user) { console.log(key); }` and post here what all keys are printed.

Comment: @Салман http://pastebin.com/SLCGDYt2 || Actually, there's `hash` in it. And I think I've just figured it out. I'll be posting answer myself in a bit..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**update**: [Solved in mongoose v3.8.19](https://github.com/LearnBoost/mongoose/issues/2378)

---

It's totally a mongoose issue.

A solution was to not go schema-less. I was using [`strict: false`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#strict) when defining my schema (for making my database schema-less)

```
var Users = mongoose.model('Users', new mongoose.Schema({
    },{strict:false}));
```

Adding `hash` here solved it.

```
var Users = mongoose.model('Users', new mongoose.Schema({
    hash: String
    },{strict:false}));
```

Comment: So properties not defined in the schema (despite being saved due to `strict:false`) do show up in `.toString` but are not accessible as a property?

Comment: @Bergi yup, seems so…

Answer (score 1):

I believe `user` is an `object` and to access object property in JS you use `.` notation(Property Accessors).

And In a code posted above I can see ,ID field is missing 'quotes',

```
user = { username: 'user1',
         salt: '3303187e50a64889b41a7a1c66d3d3c10b9dec638fdd033bee1221d30d01c5e1',
         hash: 'a174c206d88bee1594bb081dbd32d53420f6ef3d6322104f3d0722d58bc8dd8d',
         _id: '52d3177481daf59c11000001',
         __v: 0 
     };

console.log(user.hash); // accessing hash property of `user` Object.
```

### [Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vZFRJ/)

Comment: `user` is the output. I don't set it (or it's children) manually.

Comment: He's got a mongodb node application, how can he post it to jsfiddle

Comment: at least post `console.log(typeof(user));`

Comment: @laggingreflex if its Object then look at the fiddle posted above.user is object.And I am accessing `hash` property of `user`.

Answer (score 0):

Taking a hint from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10929443/nodejs-mongodb-getting-data-from-collection-with-findone) answer, can you try changing your `findOne` arguments as:

```
function(username, password, done){
    Users.findOne({username:new require('mongodb').ObjectID(username)}, function(err, user) {
        // do something here
    });
}
```

*Note: {username:**new require('mongodb').ObjectID(username)**}*

Basically, you need to construct the 'username' and not pass it as a string to `findOne`.

Comment: How does that influence the availability of the `.hash` property?

Comment: ok Thanks a tonne. This isn't the answer but this set me in right direction and I figured it out. posting answer myself in a bit..